# Where are "the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list" stored?

Tags: apt, configuration

I wanted to disable a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. I changed the extension to something else than `.list`. It was disabled but I still had a notification `N: Ignoring file 'foo.list_backup' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`. In [man sources.list](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/sources.list.5.html), I found :

> [...] Otherwise APT will print a notice
> that it has ignored a file, unless that file matches a pattern in the
> Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in which case it will be silently ignored.

If I do `apt-config dump | grep -i silent`, I get a list of patterns but I cannot find those patterns in `grep -i silent /etc/apt/apt.conf -R /etc/apt/apt.conf.d`.

Where are "the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list" stored ?

Comment: Read `man apt.conf`, as referenced in the `man` page you quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that a base list is built-in.

> The Ignore-Files-Silently list can be used to specify which files APT
> should silently ignore while parsing the files in the fragment
> directories. Per default a file which ends with .disabled, ~, .bak or
> .dpkg-[a-z]+ is silently ignored. As seen in the last default value
> these patterns can use regular expression syntax.
> [[apt.conf manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html)]